# How can I link user32.lib for an i686 application (Windows)

Tags: rust, ffi

I'm attempting to target i686-pc-windows-msvc, but this code

```rust
extern "C" {
    pub fn GetDC(hdc: *const c_void) -> *const c_void;
}
```

fails to compile with

```
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX64\\x86\\link.exe" "/NOLOGO" "/NXCOMPAT" "/LARGEADDRESSAWARE" "/SAFESEH"
...
...
"ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "ntdll.lib" "advapi32.lib" "cfgmgr32.lib" "credui.lib" "kernel32.lib" "mswsock.lib" "ntdll.lib" "secur32.lib" "synchronization.lib" "user32.lib" "ws2_32.lib" "user32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "ws2_32.lib" "userenv.lib" "msvcrt.lib"
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetDC
```

I have no errors when targeting x86_64-pc-windows-msvc and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

changing `extern "C"` to `extern "system"` fixes it